# Unable to locate Grizzly packages in Ubuntu 13.04 Server

Tags: server, openstack

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 server in my x86 based laptop and then added the desktop packages on top of it. I have downloaded all the packages using [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool). I have [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) 3.3, etc. But I am unable to locate [Grizzly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#Release_history)-specific [Nova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#Compute_.28Nova.29), [Swift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#Object_Storage_.28Swift.29), and [Glance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#Image_Service_.28Glance.29) packages ([OpenStack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack)). I am using this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep Nova
dpkg -l | grep Glance
etc.
```

Isn't Ubuntu 13.04 Server supposed to come with Grizzly automatically?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use ubuntu cloud archive https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive